# Forcing contour lines to connect in Tikz / Gnuplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to have nice contour lines of a barrier function.
When plotting I get "unconnected" contour line. Is there a way to force the smoothing ?

MWE

```
% !TEX options=--shell-escape
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width = 7cm, compat = newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
% Representing contour plot on the polytope given by
% x >=0, y>=0, 0.5x+y <=1, y>=x-0.5
% extreme points : (0,0),(0,0.5),(1,0.5),(0,1)

\begin{axis}[
enlarge x limits,
axis lines=none,
ticks=none,
view={0}{90},
small,
]
\addplot[color = violet, mark = none] coordinates{
    (0,0)
    (0,1)
    (1,0.5)
    (0.5,0)
    (0,0)
};
\addplot3[
domain=0:2.3,
domain y=0:1.3,
enlargelimits,
samples = 100,
label = false,
contour gnuplot={levels={3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6},
labels=false,
handler/.style=smooth},
]{(-ln(x)-ln(y)-ln(1-0.5*x-y)-ln(y-x+0.5))}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

and I get[image]
where you can see the disconnected part on the left.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a question about one's patience. If you increase the samples enough, the contours are pretty well connected.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width = 7cm, compat = newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.8] %<- not good, change the width instead
% Representing contour plot on the polytope given by
% x >=0, y>=0, 0.5x+y <=1, y>=x-0.5
% extreme points : (0,0),(0,0.5),(1,0.5),(0,1)

\begin{axis}[
%title={$x \exp(-x^2-y^2)$},
enlarge x limits,
axis lines=none,
ticks=none,
view={0}{90},
small,
]
\addplot[color = violet, mark = none] coordinates{
    (0,0)
    (0,1)
    (1,0.5)
    (0.5,0)
    (0,0)
};
\addplot3[
domain=0.0001:2.3,
domain y=0.0001:1.3,
enlargelimits,
samples = 301,
label = false,
contour gnuplot={levels={3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6},
labels=false,
handler/.style=smooth},
]{(-ln(x)-ln(y)-ln(1-0.5*x-y)-ln(y-x+0.5))}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the compilation time explodes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which is indeed a solution. However I was more looking for a way to force the smoothing / connecting of the contour lines without having the computation time exploding.

Comment: @vincentleclere I may be wrong but there are to the best of my knowledge two possibilities: (1) let GNUPlot do it numerically. Then you may need a lot of computation time in more complicated examples. (Obviously I do not have memory problems, otherwise I would not have posted this answer, you may consult section **6.1 Memory Limits of TEX** of pgfplots v1.17 for that.) (2) Determine the contours analytically. In this case this should be possible.